# Rails asset pipeline priority with css files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a home.scss file (associated with a home.html.erb view), does the CSS placed in there override the CSS in my application.scss or does the application.scss override any other css in the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, all the `css` files in your `/assets` directory get combined (along with application.css) to make one giant file which is applied to your application. The separate files are there to help you organize your code, but don't actually separate them in any substantive sense.

Between `application.css` and controller specific `css` files, the `application.css` file loads last, overriding whatever duplicate rules you might have specified in a controller specific version.

You actually shouldn't be putting anything other than directives in `application.css`.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Will keep my css better organized. Thank you!

Comment: Please note that this is only true if you're using `// require_tree` in your `application.css` file, in which case it loads them alphabetically within the tree. If you want to load your css in a certain order, just list them explicitly in your `application.css` manifest.

Comment: To elaborate on what @JonathanBender points out, you can take a look at the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). My answer assumed, of course, a default setup. The guide has detailed information on how to load controller specific files by nuking the require_tree rule if that's what you're ultimately after.